# How to see single commit changes made in a file?

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to see the changes that were made to a specific file in a commit.

`git show SHA` shows me too much. `git show SHA:FILENAME` is no good because that shows the entire file, not the diff.

Comment: If you are looking for the diff, why are you not using `git diff`?
Could do `git diff SHA^ SHA -- FILENAME`.

Comment: Or seems the standard way of specifying files for git works for git show also: `git show SHA -- FILENAME`

Comment: @Alderath, your second comment should be converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way:

```
git show SHA -- /path/filename
```

If it is a merge commit:

```
git show -m --first-parent SHA -- /path/filename
```

This will also show the summary of the commit. To just see the diff add `--format=''`

If you use this often, config and use and alias (feel free to use your own alias):

```
git config --global alias.diffsha 'show -m --first-parent --format=""'
git diffsha SHA -- /path/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
git diff SHA^ SHA /path/filename
```

... to compare changes between commit ref `SHA` and his previous `SHA^` for a specific path (you can also use *wildcards*).